# Can't texture hair made with geometry nodes

Tags: materials, uv, geometry-nodes, hair, surface-deform

I'm playing around using the new Geometry nodes for hair but I can't seem to apply a texture to them.

I can apply a texture to the parent object but it doesn't affect the curves child. I also tried giving the curves a material but it just stays white.

[image]

However under the surface deform modifier there is an alert stating "Invalid surface uv's on 831 curves". I'm guessing it has something to do with this but I haven't found anything about this alert.

Thanks in advance!

[Blend files in zip format (blender 3.3.0)](https://we.tl/t-u197WsKR5b)

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't add a material to the hair curves. You need add the material directly to the curves object

[image]

Also, I see you convert the curves to mesh in Geometry Nodes editor, in that case you can add a "Set Material" node and select the material that you want apply

[image]

Comment: I have changed the picture in the question. Here I have selected the curves and added a material (same material as the hair object) but it remains white.

Comment: if you can share the blend file I could review it to see where the problem is.

Comment: I added the files to a WeTransfer in the question.

Comment: I see the problem, you convert the curves to meshes on the Geometry Nodes editor, add Set Material node to the end, and that fix the problem. I leave you the screenshot of the solution above.